# Compute Engine Express two ports

Tags: node.js, tcp, google-compute-engine

i trying to open 3 ports in the compute engine but only two of them works.

tcp:3000
tcp:2525
tcp:9090

[image]

The Port 2525 is for sending mails with sendgrid. The other ports are for express(nodejs). The Port 3000 works but the Port 9090, 3001, 3002 and so on do not works.

Is it not possible to run multiple express tools on one compute engine?

Thanks.

Comment: I found my problem. This is what i add first: tcp:3000; tcp: 3001 and this is whats it should be tcp: 3000, 3001

Comment: Is it possible to post the comment as an answer and mark it as a good answer, so that other people can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. This is what i add first: tcp: 3000; tcp: 3001 but it should be tcp:3000, 3001